# Unable to create a FirestoreClient: The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation

Tags: php, grpc, laravel-10

I Can't find the appropriate version of gRPC for PHP 8.2.4 XAMPP. Also can't find the appropriate version at https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC.

As a result, laravel shows this error,
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b0sV.png)

Because of the inappropriate gRPC version terminal shows this bellow warning,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zsja.png)

I have tried the below version of gRPC
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMTLl.png)

Now what's the solution?

I have tried the below version of gRPC
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMTLl.png)